# How to remove a standard user from iMac without their Apple ID password?

Tags: macos, permission, user-account, find-my-mac

The iMac I use at work has a standard user, belonging to an ex-employee. This person left the company so I would like to remove the user account from the Mac. I have an admin account.

The problem is that I can not remove the user without their Apple ID password because of the Find my Mac feature. I have contacted the ex-employee who deleted the Mac from their iCloud using an iPhone - proved with a screenshot.

But I still not able to delete the user, macOS constantly asking for the AppleID password. I have tried rebooting etc - nothing works.

What else I have to do to remove the account? I have tried factory reset the Mac, but that's not possible without the password either.

I can contact the ex-employee if further actions needed, but obviously I can not ask for the password...

Comment: You need to contact the ex-employee and have them remove the Mac from their Apple ID.

Comment: As mentioned in the post, I have done that and the ex-employee deleted it.

Comment: https://support.apple.com/en-gb/108934

Comment: You say you can't wipe it without the password, can you clarify what step you're failing at? Can you also clarify if this is an Apple Silicon iMac (thin, flat device) or an Intel one (backside of the device is not flat)

Comment: @Ezekiel When I click on System Setting/General/Transfer or Reset/Erease All Content and Setting button, I have to enter my password, then it asks for the other users password too. Its an Apple Silicon iMac.

Comment: @Hordon If you use Recovery Mode are you able to? https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/mac-help/mchl82829c17/14.0/mac/14.0